# Four-dimensional generalization of Lens space through the gluing of solid 3-tori

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

The lens spaces $L(p,q)$ can be defined as quotients of $S^3$.
More precisely, one takes $|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2=1$ for $z_{1,2}\in \mathbb{C}$ with the identifications $(z_1,z_2)\sim (e^{2\pi i /p}z_1,e^{2\pi i q/p}z_2)$.

Alternatively, $L(p,q)$ can be thought of as the gluing of two solid 2-tori along their boundary.
In more detail: let the meridians (contractible cycle) and longitudes (non-contractible cycle) of the two solid tori be given respectively by $(\mu_1,\lambda_1)$ and $(\mu_2,\lambda_2)$.
Then the lens space $L(p,q)$ is the result of gluing when $\mu_2=q\mu_1+p\lambda_1$, i.e. the contractible cycle on torus two is of type $(q,p)$ in the homology basis of torus one.

My question is about the generalization of this set-up to four dimensions.
Suppose we consider the gluing of two solid three-tori, i.e. the space $D_2\times T^2$ with $D_2$ a disc and $T^2$ a torus.
We now take $(\mu_1,\lambda_1,\lambda_1')$ and $(\mu_2,\lambda_2,\lambda_2')$ where the $\mu_i$ are meridians and $\lambda_i,\lambda_i'$ the two ``longitudes''.
Now we take $\mu_2=q\mu_1+p\lambda_1+p'\lambda_1'$ and glue.
A subset of cases is when $p=0$ or $p'=0$, in which case we get $L(p,q)\times S^1$.

My question is: for $p\neq 0$ and $p'\neq 0$, is there another, simpler description of these manifolds, similar to how lens spaces can be thought of as quotients of $S^3$?

Comment: You have not said what a "three tori" is.

Comment: adjusted the text, hope it is clear now.

Comment: The group $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ acts $T^2$ and thus on $D_2 \times T^2$. Using this action, I think we can always force $p=0$ or $p'=0$ (Euclid's algorithm) which makes our space into $L( \gcd(p, p'),q) \times S^1$.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Thanks for the answer!